# Ruby increment string "0001" to use in .each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to figure out how to increment a string "0001" inside of a .each ruby on rails model. I'm trying to use the number 0001 to put in a file path for active storage to import a pdf file.

The pdf file is exported from another program that auto increments the file name 0001_file.pdf and I have no way of changing that process.

I tried `"0000".next` but the number remains the same "0001".

```
    items.each do |f|
      num = "0000".next
      f.doc.attach(io: File.open("file/path/#{num}_file.pdf"), filename: "#{num}_file.pdf",   content_type: "application/pdf")
    end
```

What is the best way to save the string e.g. "0002" outside of the .each so it can be used to increment for the next iteration?

```
0001_file.pdf  
0002_file.pdf  
0003_file.pdf  
0004_file.pdf
```

Comment: Write `num '0000'` outside the loop then `num.next!` (or `num.succ!`) within the loop.

Comment: Er, `num = '0000'` outside the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of digits is less than four it will add leading zeros to make it 4 digits.

```rb
n = 4
file_num = 1
items.each do |f|
      num = file_num.to_s.rjust(n, '0')
      f.doc.attach(io: File.open("file/path/#{num}_file.pdf"), filename: "#{num}_file.pdf",   content_type: "application/pdf")
      file_num += 1
    end
```

1 will be 0001, 12 will be 0012

Answer (score 1):

Just add 0 and check the example below.
0001,
0010,
9999,
0919

```
 items.each_with_index do |f, index|
      num = sprintf '%04d', index + 1
      f.doc.attach(io: File.open("file/path/#{num}_file.pdf"), filename: "#{num}_file.pdf",   content_type: "application/pdf")
end
```

```
[1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |i, index|
    fileName = sprintf '%04d', index + 1
    puts fileName
end
```

Answer (score -1):

May be it isn't a best way but for workaround you can do like this

```
val = "000"
items.each.with_index(1) do |f, index|
  num = val + index.to_s
  f.doc.attach(io: File.open("file/path/#{num}_file.pdf"), filename: "#{num}_file.pdf",   content_type: "application/pdf")
end
```

This should result incremented value of num in each iteration like this
0001,
0002,
0003